# Pull a list of json-formatterd strings from a redis database into a Pandas dataframe

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, redis

I have a webapp that reads from a redis database. The database returns a List of Strings in json format. See this code snippet:

```
import redis
r = redis.StrictRedis(**redis_config)
keys = r.keys(pattern="*")
redis_values = r.mget(keys)
print(values[0:2])
print(type(redis_values))
print(type(redis_valus[0]))

Output:

['{"timestampx": "1621544968.075360000", "length": "528", "dscp": "0", "srcip": "172.16.1.2", "destip": "172.17.4.2"}', '{"timestampx": "1621544968.075750000", "length": "96", "dscp": "0", "srcip": "172.17.4.2", "destip": "172.16.1.2"}']
<class 'list'>
<class 'str'>
```

I cannot get this List of JSON strings into a Pandas dataframe. If I use:

```
myFrame = pd.DataFrame(redis_values)
print(myFrame.head()

Output:

                                                   0
0  {"timestampx": "1621620153.864122000", "length...
1  {"timestampx": "1621620111.615499000", "length...
2  {"timestampx": "1621620157.386244000", "length...
3  {"timestampx": "1621620123.367638000", "length...
4  {"timestampx": "1621620152.200464000", "length...
```

That's a 1-column frame with strings, not a 5-column frame with the data pulled from JSON.

What if I use read_json?

```
myFrame = pd.read_json(redis_values)

Output:
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>
```

That fails completely.

What if I convert the List of strings to a List of JSON objects?

```
myJson = []
for rv in redis_values:
    rv = json.loads(rv)
    myJson.append(rv)
myFrame = pd.read_json(myJson)

Output: 

ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>
```

If I dump redis_values to a file and then use read_json it works, but that's incredibly inefficient.

```
f = open('myjson.txt','w')
for rv in redis_values:
    f.write(rv+'\n')
f.close()
myFrame = pd.read_json('myjson.txt', lines=True)
```

Converting a List of Strings in JSON to a DataFrame shouldn't be this difficult. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `json.loads` with `pd.DataFrame`

**Ex:**

```
import json

df = pd.DataFrame(map(json.loads, vals))  # OR redis_values
print(df)
```